# How to fix the ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotAllowedError: play() when reload page in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-audio

***TS***

```
 limitExceed(params: any) {
        params.forEach((data: any) => {
          if (data.percent === 100) {
            this.createNotification('warning', data.sensor, false);
          } else if (data.percent >= 56 && data.percent <= 99.99) {
            this.createNotification('warning', data.sensor, true);
          }
        });
      }
      createNotification(type: string, name: string, types: boolean): void {
            const textColor = '#ff0000';
            const title = 'High humidity!';
            let subtitle: any;

            timer(1000, 300000).subscribe(() => {
              // const subTitle: any;
              if (types) {
                subtitle = name + 'humidity has reached the minimum limit';
              } else {
                subtitle = name + ' humidity has reached the maximum';
              }

              this.notification.config({
                nzPlacement: 'bottomRight',
                nzDuration: 5000,
              });

              this.playWithAudio(type, title, subtitle, textColor);
            });
          }

          playWithAudio(type: string, title: string, subtitle: string, textColor: string) {
            const AUDIO = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById('audio');
            if (AUDIO) {
              AUDIO.muted = true; // temporarily revolves play error on browser
              const playPromise = AUDIO.play();

              this.notification.create(type, title, subtitle, {
                nzStyle: { color: textColor, 'border-left': textColor + ' 5px solid' }
              });

              if (playPromise !== null) {
                playPromise.then(() => { AUDIO.play(); })
.catch(error => { AUDIO.play(); });
              }
            }
          }
```

***HTML***

```
<audio id="audio" hidden>
  <source src="./assets/audio/notif.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

How to fix the ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotAllowedError: play() when it reload the page?

cause when I run the app the audio is working, but when I try to reload the alert/notification is working but the audio doesn't work cause there's an error. which is the ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotAllowedError: play()

How I will fix it?

Comment: When you do AUDIO.play() in the .then(), it is returned a Promise, you need to do a .then and .catch in it too

Comment: i added a catch. then I try to play() the audio it the same error ```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotAllowedError: play()```

Comment: @OscarVelandia I already updated my code.

Comment: I mean to say 

playPromise.then(() => {
  AUDIO.play()
    .then(console.log) // Here you can see the response.
})
.catch(console.log); // Here you can see the error.

If you see your playPromise is the same as AUDIO.play(). If you can do a example in codebox, I can help you in a best way.

Comment: is this correct?
```notificationAudio.play().then(err => console.log(err));``` or  ```notificationAudio.play().then(err => console.log(playPromise));```

Comment: @OscarVelandia the response from catch ```Promise {<rejected>: DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://goo.g…}```.

Comment: @OscarVelandia response from the ```notificationAudio.play().then(err => console.log(playPromise));``` ```Promise {<resolved>: undefined}```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you doesn't have an audio source, I modify your playWithAudio function with

```js
 playWithAudio() {
    const AUDIO = document.querySelector('audio');

    if (AUDIO) {
      AUDIO.muted = false;
      AUDIO.play();
    }
  }
```

And your HTML with

```
  <audio id="audio" hidden>
    <source src="https://www.kenney.nl/content/3-assets/128-ui-audio/preview.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  </audio>
```

save the AUDIO.play() promise in a variable is useful if you need to do something after the file is played, in other case, you can just use it (how I do in the example)

Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-colden-yzlno

Comment: AUDIO.play().then(console.log) - response ```undefined```. catch - response ```core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotAllowedError: play()``

Comment: I can't help you with the code in the OP, if you can upload a reproducible code in codesanbox I will help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-audio-player-bwcjbt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: kindly check sir

Comment: where did you update it sir? on the stackblitz? or your answer here? still the same Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play()

Comment: I edit the response, with this link https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-colden-yzlno